# Fluent python FrenchDeck 1.1

Tags: python

In the book fluent python's Frenchdeck problem. We have the code.

```
import collections

Card = collections.namedtuple('Card',['rank','suit'])

class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2,11)]+list('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades diamond clubs hearts'.split()
    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suits) for suits in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)
    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self._cards[position]
```

This file is saved with the name FrenchDeck.py

The code makes sense, but I get the problem when I try to **import this FrencDeck module in pycharm's console & use it.**

Ex:-

```
import FrenchDeck
```

`beer_card = Card('7','diamonds')`

I get the error.

```
File "<ipython-input-39-ad5eb73b9823>", line 1, in <module>
    beer_card = Card('7','diamonds')
NameError: name 'Card' is not defined
```

But if I use the below code, I dont get any error & it works fine.

```
beer_card = FrenchDeck.Card('7','diamonds')
>>>card(rank='7', suit='diamonds')
```

can you tell me why

`self._cards = [Card(rank, suits) for suits in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]`

does not use the Card eventhough it is put in init

Thanks

Comment: That’s how it works. If you want to create the name `Card` in your namespace, explicitly `from FrenchDeck import Card`.

Comment: @deceze thankyou for the explanation

Comment: @deceze can you tell me why self._cards = [Card(rank, suits) for suits in self.suits for rank in self.ranks] does not use the Card eventhough it is put in __init__

Comment: What does that mean? How “doesn’t it use `Card`”?

Answer (score 0):

Importing `FrenchDeck` brings the definitions in `FrenchDeck` into scope, but you still have to specify the module to use the definition `Card` So you have to use `FrenchDeck.Card`

By the way, if you write a larger program, keeping the import statements like `import FrenchDeck` is much easier to maintain the code because it is obvious where `Card` comes from because you have to put `FrenchDeck.Card` - much better than using `from FrenchDeck import *` or `from FrenchDeck import Card`. Also using simple import statements makes it much less likely that a variable name you use might override an imported name.

Comment: I see that makes more sense, I was thinking from Java POV where just an import would actually import everything.